# Vertical Margin Separation in SVM

Tags: vectors, machine-learning

In a Support Vector Machine, the margins are defined as
$$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{x_i}+b\ge1\text{ for }x_i \text{ in class }+1$$
$$\vec{w}\cdot\vec{x_i}+b\le-1\text{ for }x_i \text{ in class }-1$$

I understand that maximizing $\Vert w \Vert$ will maximize the distance between the margins given the constraints, however I'm having a hard time with the following:

The margins are set in such a way that their y-intercepts (in 2D space) will always be 2 units apart. It's easy to see how, with this constraint, the distance between the margins will depend only on their angle, but **why would we limit the vertical separation of the margins?** Is there no situation in which the optimal margins would have greater vertical separation?

Edit: Horizontal margin lines come to mind. If the ideal margin lines (again, in 2D space) have a slope of zero, then the distance between them might need to be greater than (or perhaps less than) 2. Am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 0):

Answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264645/vertical-separation-of-margins-in-svm/

The one is a result of scaling and does not limit the vertical space between the margins.